# Find an Element in a Linked List

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, linked-list

The find function is designed to start at the given node and return the index of the node with the value valueInput (indices start at 0). Return -1 if valueInput does not exist.
How can this code be improved, optimized and free of potential runtime errors?
Please note I am new to data structures and algorithms.

```
#include <iostream>


class Node {
    public:
        int value;
        Node* next = NULL;
};

void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    /* allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = 
            (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

    /* put in the data */
    new_node->value = new_data; 

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref); 

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node; 
}

int find(struct Node *head, int n) 
{ 
    int count = 1; 

    //if count equal too n return node->data 
    if(count == n) 
    return head->value; 

    //recursively decrease n and increase  
    // head to next pointer  
    return find(head->next, n-1);  
} 

int main() 
{ 
    struct Node* head = NULL; 

    push(&head, 1); 
    push(&head, 4); 
    push(&head, 1); 
    push(&head, 12); 
    push(&head, 1);   

    printf("Element at index 3 is %d", find(head, 3));   
    getchar(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why somebody voted it down. Seems like a fine question +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Overall

You don't use encapsulation. Which makes your list vulnerable to incorrect initialization and accidental incorrect modification from outside the list.

You use several C based style choice rather than C++ style which make your codde harder to read.

### Code Review

Only a list of `int`?

```
class Node {
    public:
        int value;          // int only
        Node* next = NULL;
};
```

---

Passing a pointer to a pointer. You can simplify this by passing a reference.

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
```

---

In C++ you don't need to use struct keyword when using struct types.

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
```

---

A better declaration would have been:

```
void push(Node*& head_ref, int new_data)
```

---

C++ you should always use new (rather than the malloc family).

```
    /* allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = 
            (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

There are two reasons for this:

1. If your code combines both C and C++ memory allocation you need to track which is which and use the correct de-allocation method. Thus it is best to simply use one allocation method then you always know how to deallocate it.
2. Using `new` calls the constructor to initialize the object.
   Remember this line from your class declaration.

   ```
       Node* next = NULL;
   ```

This is not going to happen if you call `malloc()` you must use `new` to get that to happen.

3. Its also simpler to write:

   ```
   Node* new_node = new Node{new_data, *head_ref};
   ```

---

Your find returns the `nth` index of the list. But your index is 1 based. Most C based languages use a zero based index. But if I pass `0` to `find()` this function will recurse for ever.

---

In recursive funtions always check for the end of the recursion first. So as the first check in `find` you should check that the list pointer is not `nullptr`.

---

This is not modified.

```
    int count = 1;
```

So this should be a `constexpt`. The whole point of using a named type is to make the code more expressive. A better name would help the code be more expressive.

---

Don't leave redundant code commented out. Delete it.

```
    //if count equal too n return node->data
```

Source control system allow you to keep older versions of the code around

It is now easy to install git on all machines learn to use it.

---

Use better indentation

```
    if(count == n) 
    return head->value;
```

---

In C++ we use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`.

```
    struct Node* head = NULL;
```

The difference is that `nullptr` is correctly typed as a pointer, while NULL is a macro (bad) for an integer (bad type). Thus you can not incorrectly use `nullptr` while `NULL` can be abused.

---

In C++ we use the C++ streams `std::cout`.

```
    printf("Element at index 3 is %d", find(head, 3));
```

The C++ streams have a more advanced type checking system that prevents accidents.

```
    std::cout << "Element at index 3 is " << find(head, 3);
```

### Beter implementation

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    struct Node {
            T value;
            Node* next;
    };
    Node*   root;

    public:
        LinkedList()
            : root(nullptr)
        {}
        ~LinkedList() {
            while(root) {
                Node* next = root->next;
                delete root;
                root = next;
            }
        }
        LinkedList(LinkedList const&)            = delete;
        LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList const&) = delete;

        void push(T const& new_data) 
        {
            root= new Node{new_data, root};
        }

        int find(int n) 
        { 
            Node* result = findElement(root, n);
            if (result == nullptr) {
                throw std::runtime_error("message"); 
            }
            return result->value;
        }
    private:
        Node* findElement(Node* n, int n) {
            if (n == nullptr) {
                return nullptr;
            }

            if (n == 0) {
                return n;
            }
            return findElement(n->next, n-1);
        } 
}
```

Main.cpp

```
int main() 
{ 
    LinkedList<int> list; 

    list.push(1); 
    list.push(4); 
    list.push(1); 
    list.push(12); 
    list.push(1);   

    std::cout << "Element at index 3 is " << find(head, 2) << "\n";   
    getchar(); 
}
```

Comment: What would the main function look like in your implementation?

Comment: @DarnocEloc Added the main for you.

Comment: I want to search/find the element by value and return its index, you’re doing the opposite.

Comment: @DarnocEloc I am doing the same as your code above. I am sure you can fix it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the thorough explanations, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. You never check if `head` was assigned a valid pointer before dereferencing it here:

```
int find(struct Node *head, int n) 
{ 
    int count = 1; 

    //if count equal too n return node->data 
    if(count == n) 
    return head->value; // <--- here

    //recursively decrease n and increase  
    // head to next pointer  
    return find(head->next, n-1); // <--- here 
}
```

#### 2. Why are you using `malloc` in c++ code?

```
 (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

#### 3. Missing functions from your stack interface

Where are the functions like `pop()` and an appropriate destructor to free memory, and remove single nodes from the stack?